# Cancel idle state by code…

Tags: delphi

I am detecting the machine Idle state and if Idle, I perform an action.

One of the actions must be canceling this state otherwise it will enter a loop.
I want to prevent re-entry into my idle loop when I'm executing in it, how do I do this?

Comment: I'm confused, (A): is some other app preventing your machine from entering idle and do you want to prevent that? or (B) do **you** want to prevent the machine from ever entering idle?

Comment: @Johan: I think he wants to prevent re-entrancy in his "OnSystemIdle" handler code.

Comment: That is it. I want to prevent re-entrancy.

Comment: If you're talking about the Application.OnIdle event handler, then the only way you can get re-entrance is if you call something that allows the handling of messages. Don't do that. That's not what that event is for. Break your idle task into smaller pieces so you can do just one piece at a time. The application will keep calling your handler as long as it has no messages to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pressing a key i guess this will do the trick

```
  keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT,0),0,0);
  keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT,0),KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

This presses the shiftkey and the system will think the computer isn't idle any more...

Comment: -1, now people will wonder why their screensaver isn't active or why the screen hasn't turned off when they return from lunch. Just use a boolean flag in your idle event.

Answer (score 5):

One way to prevent re-entrance is to memorize if you have entered the event handler:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FInOnIdle: Boolean;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if FInOnIdle then Exit;

  FInOnIdle := True;
  try
    
  finally
    FInOnIdle := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Johan: It still took both of you long enough after my hint in the questions comments :-) (I would have done it, if not for a deadline next wednesday...)

Comment: @Johan, I gave the answer first, but you beat me in correct the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a flags in your form's vars that tests to see if you're already in an idle loop:

```
interface

type TForm1 = class(TForm)
...
private
...
  InIdleLoop: boolean;
...

implementation

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if InIdleLoop then exit;
  InIdleLoop:= true
  try
   //Do your idle processing here

  finally
    InIdleLoop:= false;
  end; {try}
end;
```